# JetBrains IDEA автосмена раскладки. Как отключить?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains

Это самая раздражающая бага в мире, она была в Windows 7 когда в каждом окне сохранялась своя раскладка клавиатуры. Теперь я обнаружил её в JetBrains.

Воспроизводится так:
1. Перейдите в редактирование любого файла, переключитесь в не En раскладку(допустим RU)
2. ctrl+N поиск класса(или файла) по имени, переключаемся на английский, ищем. Возвращаемся в окно редактирования, и оп, язык откатился к RU

Я печатаю в слепую, помню какой язык выбран. Если был английский, я могу начать печатать думая что сейчас английский, или попытаться сменить язык не глядя на текущую раскладку, так как я помню что была EN последней. Но нет! Язык откатился, это безумно раздражает.

Может кто знает как убрать эту опцию? У меня IntelliJ IDEA, но думаю эта "супер интеллектуальная опция" присутствует и в других сериях линейки.

Comment: Это настройка OS а не IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: НЕТ! В других окнах(Windows 10) у меня не меняется автоматически раскладка клавиатуры. Это настройка IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/gLcsUZErvHtBUg проверяйте. Это глюки винды. =)

Comment: галочка снята "Позволить выбирать метод ввода для каждого приложения" Вы все путаете проблему смены языка при переключении окон РАЗНЫХ программ, с проблемой переключения языка в приделах ОДНОЙ ПРОГРАММЫ и её всплывающих формочек! У любого кто поставит язык в RU, а потом вызовет ctr+N(поиск файлов в проекте), там переключится на EN при выходе из окна поиска, снова получится RU раскладку...